# Rails - DRY'ing up new/edit pages in nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, dry, nested-resources

My new and edit pages for multiple levels of nested resources all worked fine when I had a flat resource structure. Since nesting resources for the purpose of making a more logical structure, these pages have been a bit broken. 
I have a single form template for each model which starts as this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact, html: {:class => "well form-vertical"} do |f| %>
```

This works perfectly for the non-nested resources (such as Contact, as above), allowing create and update actions to work as expected.

With the nested resources however (such as Service, as below), the new action stops working. When I browse to the 'new' page, I get the error:

```
Error 500: undefined method `services_path' for #<#<Class:0x0b3512b4>:0xb42b2c58>
```

My routes.rb for the relevant section is as follows:

```
resources :contacts,   shallow: true,     :except => [ :destroy ] do
  resources :accounts, shallow: true,     :except => [ :destroy ] do
    resources :services,                  :except => [ :destroy ]
  end
end
```

The controller actions for new and edit for contacts and services are:

Contact:

```
def new
  @contact = Contact.new
...
def edit
  @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
```

Service:

```
def new
  @service = Service.new(account_id: params[:account_id])
...
def edit
  @service = Service.find(params[:id])
```

The relevant output from `rake routes` is:

```
   account_services        GET    /accounts/:account_id/services(.:format)         services#index
                           POST   /accounts/:account_id/services(.:format)         services#create
new_account_service        GET    /accounts/:account_id/services/new(.:format)     services#new
       edit_service        GET    /services/:id/edit(.:format)                     services#edit
            service        GET    /services/:id(.:format)                          services#show
                           PUT    /services/:id(.:format)                          services#update
           contacts        GET    /contacts(.:format)                              contacts#index
                           POST   /contacts(.:format)                              contacts#create
        new_contact        GET    /contacts/new(.:format)                          contacts#new
       edit_contact        GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)                     contacts#edit
            contact        GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)                          contacts#show
                           PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)                          contacts#update
```

Comment: As I see you really do not have `services_path` helper. Only `account_services_path`.

Comment: I see that too, but if in my form I add: `url: account_services_path(account_id: params[:account_id])` then the new action works fine but the edit stops working, because the edit url needs :id, not :account_id.

Comment: My main concern here is keeping things simple, I don't want to have to create an entirely new page just because I have to change one line, where every other line is identical.

Comment: If you used scaffold generator to create views for resources it could insert improper helper in your code by default. Try to inspect your `new` page for it.

Comment: No scaffolding, I used rails generate to create all models, views, and controllers separately. I've already looked over the code for the pages that are working and the ones that aren't repeatedly, neither of them have changed, the only difference is that I've nested some resources now, when previously they were a flat structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this was entirely the wrong approach to be taking to this problem. I instead rewrote my create routes to POST straight to `/:controller` and it then worked with just using `simple_form_for @contact, html: {class: "well form-vertical"} do |f|`

Answer (score 0):

`<%= simple_form_for(@contact, :html => {:class => "well form-vertical"}) do |f| %>` Use instead of

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact, html: {:class => "well form-vertical"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: When I add the brackets in like that, I get the error `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'`

Comment: <%= simple_form_for ( @service, html: {:class => "well form-vertical"} ) do |f| %>

Comment: After removing that errant space and retrying it: `<%= simple_form_for( @internet_service, html: {:class => "well form-vertical"} ) do |f| %>` the edit and update actions work, but browsing to 'new' gives the same error as before: `Error 500: undefined method 'services_path'`

Comment: remove space between form_for(

Comment: Done, as per previous comment.

Comment: <%= simple_form_for( @internet_service, html:=> {:class => "well form-vertical"} )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16464/discussion-between-ganesh-kunwar-and-bdx)